# Переопределение поведения TextBox при нажатии Tab

Tags: vba, access, textbox, tab

При нажатии на кнопку <kbd>Tab</kbd> при редактировании текста в `TextBox` необходимо вставить 4 пробела и установить курсор в конец строки.
Беда в том, что после нажатия <kbd>Tab</kbd> выделяется весь текст в `TextBox`, а курсор "убегает" в самое начало `TextBox`.

Код использую следующий:

```
Private Sub txt_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyTab) Then
    s = txt.Text & Space(4)
    txt = s
    With txt
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(.Text)
    End With

End If
End Sub
```

Однако, если кусок кода с `With` перенести на кнопку, то все работает хорошо. Понимаю, что это связано со "стандартной" реакцией Access на кнопку <kbd>Tab</kbd>, но как исправить это, ума не приложу.
В свойстве `TextBox` "Переход по TAB" установлено значение "нет".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub txt_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyTab) Then
    KeyCode=0
    s = txt.Text & Space(4)
    txt = s
    With txt
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(.Text)
    End With

End If
End Sub
```